# A very naive question on maximum of a linear function

Tags: calculus

Had no problem rote doing optimization questions which require me to use calculus (first derivative) to find the maximum of a function, in which it is straightforward.

However, I realised that first derivative cannot be applied to linear function of one order, an example would be like y = x, range is $[0,1]$. You just have to graph it out and use the range/domain to find the maximum value of $y$. So am I right to say that this kind of function will always fail using first derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual "rote" method of finding max/min (of a differentiable function) on a *closed* interval has two steps:

1. Find the interior critical points using the first derivative.
2. Check the end points (the exterior or boundary points._

In the case of the linear function, there are no interior points, so you can move on to step two.